# Error al descargar un archivo pdf desde una url al dispositivo con flutter

Tags: flutter

Estoy intentando descargar un archivo pdf desde una url en el dispositivo utilizando los paquetes: [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio), [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) pero me produce el siguiente error:

> Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path =
>   '/data/user/0/com.example.myapp/app_flutter' (OS Error: Is a
>   directory, errno = 21) E/flutter (32289): #0      _File.throwIfError
>   (dart:io/file_impl.dart:645:7) E/flutter (32289): #1
>   _File.createSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:283:5)

Este es mi código:

```
void _donwloadDocument(String urlDocument) async {
    debugPrint('Url de descarga en donwloadDocument $urlDocument');
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
    Dio dio = Dio();
    dio.download(urlDocument, appDocPath, onReceiveProgress: (rec, total) {
      print("Downloading " + ((rec / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%");
    });
  }
```

Comment: lo estás probando en android cierto, emulador o dispositivo ?

Comment: Estoy probando en dispositivo físico con Android 9

Comment: Necesitas pedir permisos en runtime, chequea plugings de permisos

Comment: Cuando utilizo el paquete simple_permissions me produce el error: /SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat; conoces algun otro paquete o link de donde guiarme, agradezco mucho tu respuesta.